# flask-restless use pagination or get full response

Tags: python, flask, pagination, flask-restless

Sometimes I want to get from a resource the full response and sometimes I want it with pagination. Until now I was only able to use either the one or the other. 
But isn't there a way to set flask-restless to use both depending on the paramters i pass on the GET request?

If I want to disable pagination for a specific resource I change the settings like this:

```
manager.create_api(someresource, methods=['GET'], results_per_page=None)
```

But now pagination is completly disabled and that's not the behaviour I wish.

And if pagination is enabled as default it returns only the first page.
Isn't there a way to tell flask-restless to get only the first page if I specifically pass the page 1 in the query string like so:

```
GET http://someaddress/resource?page=1
```

I was actually able to solve the problem using a loop but I don't think it is a nice solution because I have to use multiple requests.

I requested the resource and fetched the total_pages and then I ran a loop to total_pages and passed each iteration as an argument in the query string for another new request to fetch each page:

```
i = 1
while i <= response.total_pages:
    page_response = requests.get("http://someurl/someresource?page=" + str(i))
    ...
```

But I don't think it is a nice way to solve that issue. If there is a possibility to change the settings on flask-restless to fetch only the first page if it is passed as an argument in the query string then I would be more than happy but if there is still another way to use both then it's also good.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the behaviour you want by disabling pagination with:

```
manager.create_api(someresource, methods=['GET'], results_per_page=0)
```

And then query the API with the `results_per_page` parameter like so:

```
GET http://someaddress/resource?results_per_page=2
```

The `results_per_page` parameter has to be a positive integer and will be your new page size. The parameter is further documented [here](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/requestformat.html#clientpagination).

---

Getting the full response without pagination is straight forward with this configuration. Just omit the `results_per_page` parameter:

```
GET http://someaddress/resource
```